# How to copy docker volume directory to host

Tags: docker, copy, host, docker-volume

I try to backup my unhealthy database from a docker container volume to my local host. I didn't found any functional script. Here is my container structure.

```
docker-desktop:/var/lib/docker# ls
builder     containers  overlay2    swarm       volumes
buildkit    image       plugins     tmp
containerd  network     runtimes    trust
docker-desktop:/var/lib/docker/volumes# ls
ba41a7f8c8b68619709139ec396363be7f40a3e6da2c4efafeb7a01e408a5dcc
cfarchitecture_data_appserver
cfarchitecture_data_database
cfarchitecture_data_pma
cfarchitecture_home_appserver
cfarchitecture_home_database
cfarchitecture_home_pma
landocasetupkenobi38ahsoka60a2ffd2ada01dc9cbe426cbf7999bb8297ec6a0_data_ca
landocasetupkenobi38ahsoka60a2ffd2ada01dc9cbe426cbf7999bb8297ec6a0_home_ca
landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_data_proxy
landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_home_proxy
metadata.db
docker-desktop:/var/lib/docker/volumes/cfarchitecture_data_database# ls
_data
docker-desktop:/var/lib/docker/volumes/cfarchitecture_data_database/_data# ls
auto.cnf            ib_buffer_pool      performance_schema
ca-key.pem          ib_logfile0         private_key.pem
ca.pem              ib_logfile1         public_key.pem
client-cert.pem     ibdata1             server-cert.pem
client-key.pem      mysql               server-key.pem
drupal8             mysql_upgrade_info  sys




docker-desktop:/var/lib/docker# ls
builder     containers  overlay2    swarm       volumes
buildkit    image       plugins     tmp
containerd  network     runtimes    trust
docker-desktop:/var/lib/docker/containers# ls
05d2cb8982e61a621a38d0443c8c067cc6585aa3275312dadc56ea972d12bb99
70b77f688c6552181044c76326e90dfcf906c2ddae25ee8450c1c1b09ea2029c
c00e38c7acc03545723ba126537cba08a8fb553b274fc5ba9fa2635a8883e370
```

Here is the latest attempts to backup my folder :

```
macpro-10:~ Yom$ docker run --rm --volumes-from c00e38c7acc03545723ba126537cba08a8fb553b274fc5ba9fa2635a8883e370 -v ~/backup:/backup ubuntu bash -c 'cd /drupal8 && tar cvf /backup/ghost-site.tar .'
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:6e9f67fa63b0323e9a1e587fd71c561ba48a034504fb804fd26fd8800039835d
Status: Image is up to date for ubuntu:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: No such container: c00e38c7acc03545723ba126537cba08a8fb553b274fc5ba9fa2635a8883e370.
See 'docker run --help'.
macpro-10:~ Yom$ c00e38c7acc03545723ba126537cba08a8fb553b274fc5ba9fa2635a8883e370
-bash: c00e38c7acc03545723ba126537cba08a8fb553b274fc5ba9fa2635a8883e370: command not found
macpro-10:~ Yom$ docker run --rm --volumes-from cfarchitecture_database_1 -v ~/backup:/backup ubuntu bash -c 'cd /data/drupal8 && tar cvf /backup/ghost-site.tar .'
bash: line 0: cd: /data/drupal8: No such file or directory
macpro-10:~ Yom$ docker run --rm --volumes-from cfarchitecture_database_1 -v ~/backup:/backup ubuntu bash -c 'cd /_data/drupal8 && tar cvf /backup/ghost-site.tar .'
bash: line 0: cd: /_data/drupal8: No such file or directory
macpro-10:~ Yom$ docker run --rm --volumes-from cfarchitecture_database_1 -v ~/backup:/backup ubuntu bash -c 'cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/cfarchitecture_data_database/_data/drupal8 && tar cvf /backup/ghost-site.tar .'
bash: line 0: cd: /var/lib/docker/volumes/cfarchitecture_data_database/_data/drupal8: No such file or directory
```

I am completely lost, I really need to backup this database (1 week of work)
thanks a lot

Comment: What is the relation between `docker-desktop` and `macpro-10`? I don't quite get it. You are showing the file structure from docker engine on the first machine and then try to use it on the other host?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i used TTY screen to access Docker structure, I can't use docker command with it because the docker command is not found. The docker command works when I use a terminal on the host alias macpro-10

Answer (score 0):

how many containers are you running? 
Can you do a list? 
`docker ps -aq` 
I hope your containers are not removed along with images before your back up operation.
Also, if the containers are running. Please stop them using `docker stop` and then try.

Please post above command outputs.

Comment: `c31153514d5f
ec31e826c68f
f3a67e5acee3
3703d697d057
82aa2d860d05
70b77f688c65
05d2cb8982e6`